# add the check_authorization callback of CanCanCan to the Grape API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancancan, ruby-grape

We are using grape api in our project. We used cancancan gem for authorization. Now we are thinking  to add the check_authorization callback of CanCanCan to the Grape API. This ensures that each and every endpoint does a authorize! call (except if it’s explicitly skipped).

I added check_authorization in ApplicationController. But it seems does not make any impact.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  check_authorization
end
```

## in my resource file

```
desc 'Get a specific job post'
  get ':id' do
    job_post = 
 JobPost.accessible_by(current_ability).find(params[:id)
  current_ability.authorize! :show, job_post
    
  present job_post, with: Entities::JobPost
 end
```

So far I understand, if any authorizaton is not declared in api file explicitly, check_authorzation method will triggers and raise cancan access denied. But I don't get any message if I don't authorize in job_post.
suppose I comment this line

```
# current_ability.authorize! :show, job_post
```

and it should raise unauthorized, if check_authorization is triggered. But it seems application controller is not connected with grape apis.

Comment: @dbugger, can you please check my updated message?

Comment: From my limited understanding of Grape -- it mounts a entirely separate controller stack based on the Grape::API class -- nothing goes through the Rails ApplicationController.